# I saw a ghost figure appear in fallout shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was just playing fallout shelter, taking care of my vault. When i was switching one of dwellers from the fitness room to the lounge. After the dweller entered the lounge a strange melody started playing, and when it finished a man in a long coat appeared in the corner. After like 5 sec he disapeared again. I managed to take a screenshot of him. But after that i looked it up on the internet but i found nothing. But who is this and what does he proclaim/mean???

Comment: How *mysterious*! So you're asking who this *stranger* is?

Answer (score 7):

He is the Mysterious Stranger.

Clicking on him gives you caps.

I got 2460 caps the last time.

Listen for a piano sound. You have a few seconds to find him and get the caps.

He disappears after a second sound is played.

He was added in [version 1.2](https://youtu.be/kizzTSyvoLQ)

You must click on him while he is standing there.